# Error "Name is too short or empty!"

Tags: javascript, php, json, sendmail

I have always trouble with sendingmail forms I think it is because of so many different codes necessary that's why;

Here is mail puzzle, starting with html code then script end then php

HTM CODE:

```
<div class="col-2 animation_fade_in_block">
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form_2">
<div id="contact_body">
<label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required class="input-field" placeholder="Name *" /> 
</label>
<label>
<input type="email" name="email" required class="input-field" placeholder="E-mail *" /> </label>
<label>
<input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="19" required placeholder="Phone *" class="tel-number-field long" /> </label>
<label for="field5">
<textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field" required placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
</label>
<label>
<input type="submit" id="submit_btn_2" class="btn" value="Send message " /> </label>
</div>
<div id="contact_results"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$("#submit_btn_2").click(function() {

    var proceed = true;
    //simple validation at client's end
    //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
    $("#contact_form_2 input[required=true], #contact_form_2 textarea[required=true]").each(function() {
        $(this).css('border-color', '');
        if (!$.trim($(this).val())) { //if this field is empty 
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
        }
        //check invalid email
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if ($(this).attr("type") == "email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
        }
    });

    if (proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
    {
        //get input field values data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'user_name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'user_email': $('input[name=email]').val(),

            'phone_number': $('input[name=phone]').val(),
            'subject': $('select[name=subject]').val(),
            'msg': $('textarea[name=message]').val()
        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('../php/contact.php', post_data, function(response) {
            if (response.type == 'error') { //load json data from server and output message     
                output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';
            } else {
                output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';
                //reset values in all input fields
                $("#contact_form_2  input[required=true], #contact_form_2 textarea[required=true]").val('');
                $("#contact_form_2 #contact_body").fadeOut("fast"); //hide form after success
            }
            $("#contact_form_2 #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#contact_form_2  input[required=true], #contact_form_2 textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() {
    $(this).css('border-color', '');
    $("#contact_results").fadeOut("fast");
});


$("#submit_btn_2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Rest of your code

});
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<3){ // If length is less than 3 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = "

    Name:".$user_name."\r\n
    Email: ".$user_email."\r\n
    Phone Number: ". $phone_number."\r\n
    Message:".$message
    ;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, "Message from site",  $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => '

            <div class="popup_icon"><i class="fa fa-check "></i></div>
<div class="popup_title">Спасибо за контакт со STYX!</div>
<div class="popup_subtitle">Мы ответим очень скоро.</div>


'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

What is the problem; problem is I have "Name is too short or empty!" error even when I write very long name. Is there anybody that can help to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you debug it and find out where the problem comes from? Narrow it down to a language at least.

Comment: Put a `echo $_POST["user_name]"` in your PHP script an test if your data is really posted to your PHP script.

Comment: No I couldn't find where problem is coming, that's why I put all codes, but as I understand problem somewhere on script.js

Answer (score 0):

There could be two things you need to trouble shoot.

1. Your jQuery script is failing to send the `user_name` POST or failing to find the value from the selector.
2. Your PHP is sanitising `$_POST['user_name']` and removing a lot of the string.

---

Troubleshooting:

1.
Using Chrome or Firefox, open the Developer console or Developer Tools (in Chrome it is found in `Options > More Tools > Developer Tools`

Click on the Console Tab.
Next two the `>` symbol enter `$('input[name=name]').val()`
If it returns `undefined` - this means the browser cannot find this selector.

Potential Fix, use this instead:
`$("input[name='name']").val()`

Because the `name` attribute is also `name` jQuery may have a hard time parsing this. *speculation.

---

2.
Check to see if your PHP is getting the right `$_POST` data

I like to do a quick and dirty

```
echo json_encode(array("type"=>"error", "text" => print_r($_POST,true));
exit();
```

At the very start of the script.

Next try commenting out:

```
//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
// > $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

If this works, then you know the Filter var is killing this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all ideas, first of all thanks for all of them. 
Problem was there are two contact form and both "name"parameters were mixed. I add #contact_form and #contact_form_2 so fixed..

```
            'user_name'     : $('#contact_form input[name=name]').val(), 
            'user_email'    : $('#contact_form input[name=email]').val(), 

            'phone_number'  : $('#contact_form input[name=phone]').val(), 
            'subject'       : $('#contact_form select[name=subject]').val(), 
            'msg'           : $('#contact_form textarea[name=message]').val()



            'user_name'     : $('#contact_form_2 input[name=name]').val(), 
            'user_email'    : $('#contact_form_2 input[name=email]').val(), 

            'phone_number'  : $('#contact_form_2 input[name=phone]').val(), 
            'subject'       : $('#contact_form_2 select[name=subject]').val(), 
            'msg'           : $('#contact_form_2 textarea[name=message]').val()
```